# Getting total count in JPA entitymanager query

Tags: jpa

I'm trying to execute the JPA query through entitymanager with pagination which is working fine. 
Working code is given below, but how can I get the total number of records in the database?

```
ResponseModel queryResponse = new ResponseModel();
            Query queryResult = null;
            try {

                Pageable pageable = MyUtils.buildJpaPagable(queryContext);
                queryResult = entityManager.createQuery(query);

                if(pageable!=null)
                    queryResult.setMaxResults(pageable.getPageSize())
                        .setFirstResult(pageable.getPageNumber() * pageable.getPageSize());

                long totalRecord = 0;

                queryResponse.setResponse(queryResult.getResultList()); 

                totalRecord= queryResult.getMaxResults();

                queryResponse.setTotalCount(totalRecord);

            }
```

Comment: You have to do count query again for your query without limit and offset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a count query for your `query` by replaceing the `select whatever` part with select count(*).

How to do that depends on the origin and kind of `query`.